# issue in odbc query

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have the code below which i use for the login authentication part.
It was all in mysql, and i did my best to transform it to odbc

i get an error though: must be in `$row = $query->odbc_assoc();` i guess

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal ) or die("Connection could not established");

$query = $connection->'SELECT Level_access FROM users WHERE ID = "'.$connection->addslashes($_SESSION['user_id']).'"';
$row = $query->odbc_assoc();

$connection->close();
```

Can someone check this, it might be totally wrong written though..
Question: is mysql_escape_string equivalent to addslashes in odbc connection?

Thanks

Comment: i get :
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' here: $query = $connection->'SELECT Level_access FROM users WHERE ID = "'.$connection->addslashes($_SESSION['user_id']).'"';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: is mysql_escape_string equivalent to addslashes in odbc connection?

No, and `addslashes` is *never* the right tool!  Through simple manipulation of character sets, it's amazingly trivial to bypass the simple layer of escaping that `addslashes` creates.  This still leaves you wide-open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Further, `mysql_real_escape_string` is for MySQL only, and only operates correctly with an open MySQL connection with a declared character set.

This doesn't begin to touch the fact that your syntax is entirely bogus.  `odbc_connect` returns a resource, not an object.  Trying to call a method on it will do nothing other than kill the script.

If you need to use OBDC to connect to SQL Server instead of something modern like the [sqlsrv extension](http://php.net/book.sqlsrv), then at least use [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) via [`PDO_ODBC`](http://php.net/ref.pdo-odbc).  Both of these options offer you [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), which are usually an effective defense against SQL injection.  Sqlsrv's prepared statements are executed on the server, where they should be, while PDO's are done internally instead of at the server.  Just be sure to pass the connection character set in the connection string, and make sure that all user data you'll be passing along is in the right charset, and you'll be fine.